# specify height of flexbox other than 100vh

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a `form` inside a `div` inside. The `div` is inside another `div`.

```
<div class="div__signup"> <!-- takes the complete width/height of content section -->
  <div class="content_div--white"> <!-- contains the form. Adjust this div to create a border around the form -->
    <form class="signup-form" actions="">
      <label for="firstname" class="first-name">First Name</label>
      <input id="firstname" type="text">

      <label for="lastname" class="last-name">Last Name</label>
      <input id="lastname" type="text">

      <label for="email" class="email"> Email</label>
      <input id="email" type="email">

      <label for="password" class="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password">

      <label for="verify-password" class="verify-password">Verify Password</label>
      <input id="verify-password" type="password">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

This html is inside a `css-grid` which has 3 rows - navigation, content and footer.

```
.css-grid-container{
  height:100vh; /*???*/
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;  /* 1 columns*/
  grid-template-rows: auto 15fr 1fr; /* 3 rows. Auto takes height of navigation, remaining is divided into 2 rows, middle row (content) is 15 times larger than the 3rd row (footer).*/
}
```

I want the `html` of the form page to be at the center of the content section of the `css-grid`. If I use `flexbox`, I suppose I have to provide specific height for the flexbox. The only height parameter I know is `100vh` which equals height of the viewport.

```
.div__signup{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh; /*need something else than 100vh as I dont want alignment w.r.t viewport */
}
```

But I want the form to be at the center of the content section of the grid, not the center of the viewport. How could I align the form to the center of the content section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that `.div__signup` is a child of a *grid item*, here are two suggestions:

1. Using absolute position

   ```
   .css-grid-item {
     position: relative;
   }

   .div__signup {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0; top: 0; 
     right: 0; bottom: 0;

     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;      
   }
   ```
2. Make the grid item a flex container

   ```
   .css-grid-item {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;      
   }
   ```

*Do note, sample 2 may, or may not work, based on how the `justify-content`/`align-items` is set on the `css-grid-item`.*

---

Assumed HTML

```
<div class="css-grid-item">

    <div class="div__signup"> <!-- takes the complete width/height of content section -->
      <div class="content_div--white"> <!-- contains the form. Adjust this div to create a border around the form -->
        <form class="signup-form" actions="">
          <label for="firstname" class="first-name">First Name</label>
          <input id="firstname" type="text">

          <label for="lastname" class="last-name">Last Name</label>
          <input id="lastname" type="text">

          <label for="email" class="email"> Email</label>
          <input id="email" type="email">

          <label for="password" class="password">Password</label>
          <input id="password" type="password">

          <label for="verify-password" class="verify-password">Verify Password</label>
          <input id="verify-password" type="password">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks. only adding ` position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;   right: 0; bottom: 0;` worked in `.div__signup`

Comment: sorry, coming back late to this. What is the purpose of adding `.css-grid-item {
  position: relative;
}`. The position is relative to what?

Comment: @ManuChadha An absolute positioned element, here `.div__signup`, is positioned relative to the first ancestor having a position other than `static`. So for `.div__signup` to be positioned within `.css-grid-item`, `.css-grid-item` need a position. If you remove `position: relative` from `.css-grid-item`, and no other ancestor have a position, the viewport will be the one `.div_signup` will adjust to.

Comment: many thanks. I observed this behavior which made my `navbar` at the top inaccessible. Well explained! To clarify, `position: relative;` has no effect on the normal position of the `css-grid-item` because we have not specified `top`, `left` properties. As far as I understand `relative` position is w.r.t how the same element would have been placed in normal document flow. If `left`, `top `are not specified then the position is same as that in normal document flow.

Comment: @ManuChadha Correct, and additionally, a positioned element, like `relative`, is in a layer above a `static` one, so even if a `static` element would be positioned after in the markup, the `relative` would still be _on top_, w/o setting any `z-index` value.

Comment: @ManuChadha Hopefully it is worth and upvote as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

See this I use display fixed, table and table cell

```css
.seline-preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section class="seline-preloader">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <h2 class="hide">Form</h2>
     
     <!--start of your code-->
     <div class="div__signup">
        <!-- takes the complete width/height of content section -->
        <div class="content_div--white">
          <!-- contains the form. Adjust this div to create a border around the form -->

          <form class="signup-form" actions="">
            <label for="firstname" class="first-name">First Name</label>
            <input id="firstname" type="text">

            <label for="lastname" class="last-name">Last Name</label>
            <input id="lastname" type="text">

            <label for="email" class="email"> Email</label>
            <input id="email" type="email">

            <label for="password" class="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" type="password">

            <label for="verify-password" class="verify-password">Verify Password</label>
            <input id="verify-password" type="password">
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end of your code-->
      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6ys34gL/)